# Is there any "command line gui" for file transfer?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, gui

I love aptitude's gui on Debian. I like how you can select with + and de-select with -, hit 'g' and download, move up and down with j and k ( vim style ).

I'm wondering if there are any command line guis similar to Aptitude for transferring files, currently I use FileZilla but I'd like something more efficient.

Of course I'm aware that there are real command line file transfer programs but I'd like a higher level interface that's not limited by the clicking, I usually have to select dozens of files and filter through so typing the filenames of each of those, even if there's tab completion is a hassle.

And my preferred protocol is SFTP, but I occasionally do FTP if the server is setup as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one that comes to mind is [midnight commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) (the `mc` package in the Debian and Ubuntu world).

Comment: Nice! Will look into this, thank you for actually including the package name.

Comment: you would use FUSE (sshfs, ftpfs etc) to mount remote folders to your machine and then just use mc.

Comment: mc can do all sorts of file transfers by itself. No need for fuse here.